# What do I have to do to make the app connect to HC-06 successfully?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

"Hello, I need my app to connect to HC06 automatically, but currently, there seems to be an issue with the connection. I'm not sure what's causing it and how to fix it. Can anyone help me with this?"

I just started using Android Studio for the first time, and I'm not familiar with coding. So, I suspect there might be something wrong.

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var startTime: Long = 0
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private lateinit var locationManager: LocationManager
    private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 2
    private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    private lateinit var receiver: BroadcastReceiver
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    private var arduinoUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder(StrictMode.getVmPolicy())
                .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                .build()
        )
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

        // Check if device supports Bluetooth
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }

        // Check if Bluetooth is enabled
        if (!bluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // Request Bluetooth permission here
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH),
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                )
                return
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH)
            }
        } else {
            startBluetoothDiscovery()
        }
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            startBluetoothDiscovery()
        }
    }
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startBluetoothDiscovery()
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly
            }
        }
    }
    private fun startBluetoothDiscovery() {
        receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
                val action: String = intent.action!!
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND == action) {
                    val device: BluetoothDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            applicationContext,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            this@MainActivity,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                        )
                        return
                    }
                    if (device != null && device.name == "HC-06" && device.address == "98:D3:31:F6:25:CC") {
                        arduinoUUID = device.uuids[0].uuid
                        runOnUiThread {
                            textView.text = "Device Found: ${device.name}"
                            connectToDevice(device)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices
        pairedDevices?.forEach { device ->
            if (device.name == "HC-06") {
                textView.text = "Device Found: ${device.name}"
                connectToDevice(device)
            }
        }

        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
        bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()
    }

    private fun connectToDevice(device: BluetoothDevice) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
            connectToDevice(device)
        }

        val bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

            override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    // Connected to device
                } else if (newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    // Connection lost
                    // You can take further actions when the connection is lost here
                }
            }

            override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    // When all services on the device have been discovered
                    // You can perform additional actions like reading or writing values to/from desired characteristics
                } else {
                    // Error discovering services
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZAUB.png)

please ...I need help T^T

Comment: Ignore to post image for showing code or error